# Local rings of a closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question might be of the "duh" kind, but I'm still shaky on the basics.

Given a scheme $X$ and a closed subscheme $Z$ of $X$. Let $\mathscr{I}$ be the corresponding ideal sheaf, and $i:Z\to X$ be the inclusion. Then we have that $i_*\mathscr{O}_Z = \mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I}$.

My question concerns the passage to local rings; more precisely,

1. what is the relationship between the local ring $\mathscr{O}_{Z,x}$ (with $x\in Z$) and the sheaf $i_*\mathscr{O}_Z$?
2. what is the relationship between the local rings $\mathscr{O}_{Z,x}$ and $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$?

Edit: Thanks to the useful comments, I now have the following: The germ of $i_*\mathscr{O}_Z$ at $x$ is the same as the local ring $\mathscr{O}_{Z,x}$, this is done by simply writing out the definition of germ as a direct limit. This answers (1).

For (2), we use the fact that the ideal sheaf $\mathscr{I}$ is the kernel of the morphism $i^\#:\mathscr{O}_X \to i_*\mathscr{O}_Z$, then passing to germs at $x$ we find that $\mathscr{O}_{Z,x} \cong \mathscr{O}_{X,x}/\mathscr{I}_x$.

So I only need to know what exactly $\mathscr{I}_x$ is.

Comment: May I suggest that you consider a concrete affine example, where all the things are classical objects from commutative algebra?

Comment: Hint: localization is exact, apply this to the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/I \rightarrow 0$

Comment: For the first question: by the universal property of direct limit we get a homomorphism $(i_*\mathcal O_Z)_{i(x)}\to\mathcal O_{Z,x}$ and one can check that this homomorphism is bijective, hence an isomorphism.

Comment: @DavidLui Thank you for your answer. I edited the question.